# How to update a textbox item or a label while in a loop?

Tags: c#

So I have a desktop app programming in C#, vs2010. It just has 2 textboxes and a button, and what it does is, I want to enter a link to download a direct exe file in the first box, and when i submit it, while its downloading, how do I make the 2nd textbox show a percentage of the download.

If thats too hard to explain dont worry, what i'm specifically looking for is, for example if I'm doing a loop of some sort, like I have two listboxes with the same text files loaded and I want to loop through it to check for duplicates but while in the loop theres like a status type of think for example it could be saying "Checking", or "Scanning (password here)" or "Looking for (password) now..." etc.

Comment: What technology are you using? i.e. Windows Forms; WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.  It would enable you to run the download process in a separate thread, and then report progress back to the UI periodically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into using [threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178(v=vs.80).aspx) and running asynchronous processes. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582140/308012) question on updating WinForms UI asynchronously. Also, for displaying progress, you are probably going to want some form of progress bar. A progress bar control is available in both [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) and [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx), depending on which you are using. Alternately, consider using a Label or TextBlock instead of a TextBox to display a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually two questions.  The first is how to handle reporting progress of a download.  The second is a more general question about handling long running operations without blocking the UI thread.

### Answer to the 1st Question: Reporting Download Progress

I would use the DownloadFileAsync Method of a WebClient.  Assuming that your TextBox for the URL is called FileURL, that you have a ProgressBar named DownloadProgress and a button called StartDownload a very basic implementation could be something like:

```
    private void StartDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.FileURL.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
                //todo: handle mime-type and location to save to!
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(this.FileURL.Text), "SomeFileName.ext");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the progress bar back to nothing
        if (MessageBox.Show("Download Completed!", "Finished!", MessageBoxButton.OK) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            this.DownloadProgress.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //update the progress bar based on the percentage completed.
        this.DownloadProgress.Value = (double)e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

**Note:** you will have to add a reference to `System.Net` in order to use the WebClient

### Answer to the 2nd Question

I think you are looking for a `BackgroundWorker` to handle the progress through your loop.  A good starting example of this can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

You would then report the progress from your BackgroundWorker and display it on the form.

Answer (score -1):

To access a textbox text, you should reffer it like this:

```
myTextBox1.Text = "Scanning (whatever)";
```

Then you could apply the application logic

Comment: See other answers.  He's doing work in the click event which will be freezing his UI.